# How to pull data

Tags: mysql

We have these 2 tables - `places` and `ads`

```
places
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| PlaceID |  CountryCode |    Name   |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
|       1 |  AU          |  Sydney   |
|       2 |  CA          |  Sydney   |
|       3 |  US          |  Miami    |
|       4 |  AU          |  Canberra |
+---------+--------------+-----------+

ads
+------+--------+-----------+
| AdID |  Name  |  Location |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    1 |  Test  |  Canberra |
|    2 |  Test2 |  Sydney   |
|    3 |  Test3 |  null     |
|    4 |  Test4 |  Delhi    |
|    5 |  Test5 |  Miami    |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

We need to pull the **Ads** data that is NOT belong to Australia based on this country. However under Ads table there is no country specified. THe dilemma is actually because Sydney are belong 2 countries we would like NOT to include AdID=2 eventhough is Sydney.

Outcome:

```
+------+--------+-----------+
| AdID |  Name  |  Location |
+------+--------+-----------+
|    4 |  Test4 |  Delhi    |
|    5 |  Test5 |  Miami    |
+------+--------+-----------+
```

We could join this 2 tables but not sure how NOT to include this "Sydney". Again Sydney is example BUT there will be hundreds city name that belong to more than 1 country.

What is the right query to pull out this outcome?

Comment: In your Ads table, location field, store placeID instead of country name.

Comment: have you mapped both tables using any field?Please share full schema of both tables.

Comment: Are you asking how to better structure these tables to get what you want, or are you in a situation where you already have this setup and are trying to extract the data? If the latter, you are completely screwed.

Comment: I've updated the question ... is basically we need to know the query is to get the outcome what we want

Comment: @Marty: The structure is already done and has data already. We know the dilemma is ... so the just need to pull out the data based on assumption that Sydney is belong to Australia for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.*
from places p
inner join ads a on p.Name=a.Location
where p.CountryCode<>'AU'
```

**`Edited`** based on edited question and requirement

```
select *
from ads
where isnull(Location,'') not in 
(select isnull(Name,'') from places where CountryCode<>'AU')
and isnull(Location,'')<>''
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07ed5/4)**

Comment: When you do this query, Sydney will show up then because it's also belong to Canada in this instance. That's not what we want.

Comment: Just check my edited answer.. Based on new Requirement

Comment: Typo mistake corrected. Check on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07ed5/4) too

Comment: Thank you that exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure in your question, you *cannot* achieve what you want. It's completely illogical, and unfortunately impossible. How do you expect to make an association between an `ad` and a country when you haven't defined the relationship?

Your two tables currently have no relationship. Your tables *should* have looked like this:

```
locations
+----+---------+--------+
| id | country |  city  |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | AU      | Sydney | <----+
|  2 | CA      | Sydney | <--+ |
+----+---------+--------+    | |
                             | |
ads                          | |
+----+------+------------+   | |
| id | name | locationId |   | |
+----+------+------------+   | |
|  1 | Test |          2 | <-+ |
|  2 | Test |          1 | <---+
+----+------+------------+
```

This way, `ads` could have been associated with `locations` as a whole, which would include the country and city.